# What is the best way to append values to a sublist of a list in R?

Tags: r

Say I have a list `l` containing sublists, and I would like to add an element (or several elements) *at the end of each sublist* of that list.

What is the best way to implement this (simplest/fastest code)?

```
# Goal: Append given elements to each sublist of a list in R
# Example: add c(9) to sublists of list l
l <- list(c(1,2,3), c(2,1,4), c(4,7,6))
l
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3
[[2]]
[1] 2 1 4
[[3]]
[1] 4 7 6

# Desired Output: 
# l_9
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 9
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 1 4 9
# [[3]]
# [1] 4 7 6 9
```

Comment: `l_9 <- lapply(l, c, 9)`

Comment: @Roland would there be a similarly simple solution for adding `9` on the left to get `list(c(9,1,2,3), c(9,2,1,4), c(9,4,7,6))`?

Comment: `lapply(l, append, x = 9)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases is useful to use lapply function. You can see here: [apply functions](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply)

So you can just use `l <- lapply(l, c, 9)`

where c is the function of combining. Here: [c function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/c)